# Amplify 1kHz sine wave from AD9833 DDS using LMH6609 operational amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, sine, non-inverting, dds

I'm trying to amplify a 1kHz sine wave signal from the AD9833 DDS chip (0.6Vp-p) to a more usable level (6Vp-p) for a sort of function generator. I plan to work with higher frequencies as well. So I got myself the LMH6609 operational amplifier which has a high bandwidth (900Mhz) and a high slew rate (1400V/us).

I am powering the opamp with a 12V power supply and a buck converter to convert 12V to 6V for the Vcm. I am also giving the DDS signal a DC bias of 6V. I am using the opamp in a non-inverting amplifier mode with the gain set at around 5.7 (47k and 10k resistors).

I have simulated this setup using Pspice for TI, I have attached the simulation schematic and transient analysis results. It works well in the simulation.

But when I try to recreate the setup on hardware, My op-amp seems to heat up quite a bit, and the output is a straight line close to 12V. When I reduce the offset of the input signal, it acts somewhat like a voltage follower. I have attached images of my input and output signals as well.

**Simulation schematic**

[image: Simulation schematic]

**Transient analysis output**
[image: Transient analysis output]

**DDS output without any DC offset**
[image: DDS output without any DC offset]

**DDS signal with ~2V DC offset**
[image: DDS signal with ~2V DC offset]

**Op-amp output for above DDS signal as input**
[image: Op-amp output for above DDS signal as input]

Comment: Recheck that your offsets RE actually what you think they are. Resistor values chosen are not very compatible with what the op-amp needs.

Comment: Any suggestions on the resistor values?

Comment: Read the data sheet - they use resistors in the hundreds of ohms range.